# SQL Retrieve info from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am really lost with sql.. i tried to read everything but no luck.

I have two tables and need to retrieve data from them:

First Table - Workers | Second Table - Stores

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
| Worker | First_Name | Last_name |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|     10 | John       | Smith     |
|     20 | Robert     | Henry     |
|    100 | Jessica    | Bailey    |
|    120 | Kelly      | Bates     |
+--------+------------+-----------+

+--------+---------+--+
| Worker |  Store  |  |
+--------+---------+--+
|     10 | Shoe    |  |
|     20 | Clothes |  |
|    100 | Shoe    |  |
|    120 | HR      |  |
|    120 | Shoe    |  |
+--------+---------+--+
```

Select workers first name that belong to more than one store?

Select all workers first name that are in the shoe store?

Hope you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  We're not here to do all of your homework.  If you have done some research you should at least have some semblance of a solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Select workers first name that belong to more than one store

```
select Workers.First_Name
from Workers
join Stores on Stores.Worker = Workers.Worker
group by Workers.First_name
having count(*) > 1
```

Select all workers first name that are in the shoe store

```
select Workers.First_Name
from Workers
join Stores on Stores.Worker = Workers.Worker
where Stores.Store = 'Shoe'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It Worked! I was pulling my hair and all i was doing was this kinda of stuff:

SELECT 
   Worker, First_Name
FROM 
   Workers
INNER JOIN 
Stores 
ON 
Workers.First_Name =Store.Marketing;

I'm an idiot! Thanks again @Jez

Comment: No worries happy to help :)